# Empty href in <link> tag with ASP.NET MVC calls default route when replaced dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to write my MVC 5 web application. Recently, I was faced with a very unusual error in my project.
I have solved the issue, but I would like to know why it works that way?

I am changing the `href` attribute of `<link>` tag dynamically in `$(document).ready()`.
When I do that, the default route of MVC is called unnecessarily only in IE11, does not happen in other browsers.
To solve the issue, I had to remove the `href` attribute as I have shown in `_Layout.cshtml` below. I want to know why this works?

I have created a minimum verifiable code which is given below.

RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "NCB", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

NCBController.cs:

```
public class NCBController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        Session["LoggedIn"] = "true";
        return RedirectToAction("Page2");
    }

    public ActionResult Page2()
    {
        var isLoggedIn = Session["LoggedIn"].ToString();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Page2(FormCollection form)
    {
        var isLoggedIn = Session["LoggedIn"].ToString(); //Place where session is empty only in IE11 because GET:Index() was called
        return View();
    }
}
```

_NCBLayout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>_NCBLayout</title>
    <link href="" rel="stylesheet" class="oldlink" /> <!--Calls default MVC route if I use this line-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" class="oldlink" /> <!--Does not call default MVC route if I use this line-->
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oldlink = document.getElementsByClassName("oldlink").item(0);
            var newlink = document.createElement("link");
            newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            newlink.setAttribute("href", '@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")');
            newlink.setAttribute("class", "oldlink");
            document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink); //I think this line is calling the default MVC route
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NCBLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "NCB"))
{
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Page2.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page2";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NCBLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Page2</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Page2", "NCB"))
{
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
}
```

Comment: It's actually not valid in html to have link-attribute with empty href (or img with empty src) so I would recommend finding some other way to do this. Why not add the whole element in your javascript instead of changing the href?

Comment: @Esko, I have solved the issue by removing the `href` completely from my `<link>` tag. I just wanted to know why does it call my default route and why it happens only in IE?

Answer (score 1):

The `link` element is there to specify an external resource like a stylesheet. If you specify an empty `href` attribute, the browser is likely trying to load the URL you have given which will be *relative to the current page*.

If you don't want to load a stylesheet this way (it would be really odd if you did) then you need to remove that entire element.

Comment: Sorry David, I did not understand what you mean by "the browser is likely trying to load the URL you have given which will be *relative to the current page.*" Could you please elaborate? And also, why is it happening only in IE?

Comment: So if you visit a page with URL `https://www.example.com/some/page`, the browser will use that as the base. When you say load the stylesheet from `""`, the relative path that is calculated is going to be the same as the original URL. As for why it's only happening in IE, I guess the Chrome developers decided that an empty `href` is the same as no `href` and Microsoft didn't.